# Smooth modifier cause gap/hole in landscape mesh

Tags: modifiers

I have a problem when using the smooth modifier on my terrain mesh. When used it cause a gap/hole in the terrain. See the images below before and after using the modifier.

[image]
[image]

I should also mention that I have previously split the mesh and then joined the mesh back together right where this gap occurs.

As far as I can see, all normals are pointing upwards and duplicate vertices have been removed.

I hope this is easy to fix!

Thanks!

Comment: *"I have previously split the mesh and then joined the mesh back together "* so the modifier smooths vertices of one mesh - into one side, and another one - to another as likely you didn't remove double vertices after joining.

Comment: @MrZak Duplicate vertices have been removed already, but still the gap occurs.

Comment: The gap means there are duplicates otherwise modifier wouldn't move vertices away from each other. How did you remove the duplicates? If you want investigation of your exact mesh then share the file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @MrZak I just realized that the vertices were not removed. What I did before was to split the mesh and then rejoined it (did not move the meshes around or anything). But still the remove doubles function doesn't seem to work in my case? See my first post, added a animation showing the double vertices.

Comment: If you have unconnected geometry due to duplicate vertices, you will run into those kinds of errors when using subsurf. Remove doubles or weld disconnected vertces together.

Comment: Remove doubles has an option to [increase the distance](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14005/935) of verts to merge.  You also have the option of [snapping and auto merging](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/107936/935) if that fails.

Comment: @sambler Increasing the distance between vertices to merge worked very well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

1. Select mesh
2. Go into Edit Mode
3. Ctrl + TAB and select Vertex mode
4. Select all vertices by pressing A
5. Press W and select Remove doubles
6. In the options panel, set a number greater than 0

[image]